# Microsoft.DirectX library INVALIDCALL errors

Tags: vb.net, directx

I'm using the Microsoft DirectX SDK for my app to get a screenshot, and i'm getting the error:

> Error in the applcation. ErrorString = "D3DERR_INVALIDCALL"

Here's my code:

```
Imports Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D
Imports Microsoft.DirectX

Private Function fGetMe() As Control
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New fGetMeDelegate(AddressOf fGetMe))
       ' Return Me
    Else
        Return Me
    End If
End Function

Private Delegate Sub fGetMeDelegate()

Private Function sCaptureScreenDX() As Image
        Dim prp As PresentParameters = New PresentParameters()
        prp.Windowed = True
        prp.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard
        Dim dvc As New Device(0, DeviceType.Hardware, fGetMe(), CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, prp)
        Dim sur As Surface = dvc.CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, Format.A8B8G8R8, Pool.Scratch)
        dvc.GetFrontBufferData(0, sur)
        Dim gs As GraphicsStream = SurfaceLoader.SaveToStream(ImageFileFormat.Bmp, sur)
        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(gs)
        Return CType(bmp, Image)
End Function
```

`fGetMe()` is called because I'm using multiple threads and needed thread safe callbacks.

I've tried this in SlimDX and I get the same error. It occurs when I call `dvc.GetFrontBufferData(0, sur)`

Is there any specific reason this is happening?

Comment: [**The documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms889405.aspx) suggests one of your parameters is wrong. By the way, your `fGetMe()` function doesn't return anything if it needs to invoke. Put `Return Me.Invoke(New fGetMeDelegate(AddressOf fGetMe))` instead.

Comment: _**Although**_, since you're only returning the form object from your `fGetMe()` function it doesn't make any difference. You can skip the function altogether. Cross-thread exceptions are only thrown once you start accessing the form's UI-bound properties/methods. -- Returning the form thread-safely doesn't help you access it thread-safely, so you would have to invoke every time you are to access its members anyway.

Comment: Note that you are using the deprecated Managed DirectX 1.1 components from the end-of-life DirectX SDK using legacy Direct3D 9. Use SlimDX or SharpDX instead. See [Where is the DirectX SDK?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) and [DirectX and .NET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/12/09/directx-and-net/).